# In salesforce marketing cloud, how to make REST api call? How to build URL?

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, icloud-api

I am looking to build URL for making API call to Salesforce marketing cloud. I am looking to extract campaigns details and metrics through it.
Url looks like-
http://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns/

I want to know the structure for client id and secret key? and what else do it need to type in url?

Thanks
Harsh

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a package and integrate with that through Marketing Cloud. Check this out about a [how-to](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm) guide.